# Kendo grid Custom Commands or etc to edit table data and perform action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'd like to change the int status of a record and send off an email based on that change, all of which without having to redirect to a new page having the user then change the status.

I've tried to tie in column template buttons to href's of JsonResult actions but of course that redirects.

From the looks of it custom commands are my best bet but I'm hoping to try and utilize as much of the existing code I have which does everything but the emails as that part is easy once I have the table edits working successfully.

Status's =
Pending/Approve/Decline

Pending is default thus on the grid only Approve and Decline show as options for status change.

View code:-

```
{
    field: 'Application',
    template: '<a style=\'width: 80px\' class=\'btn btn-success btn-block\' href=\' + sitePath + 'Placement/_Approve?Id=#=Id#\'>Approve</button>',
    width: 50
},
{
    template: '<a style=\'width: 80px\' class=\'btn btn-warning btn-block\' href=\' + sitePath + 'Placement/_Decline?Id=#=Id#\'>Approve</button>',
    width: 50
}
```

Controller action

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult _Approve(int Id)
    {
        SBApplication sba = _db.SBApplications.Find(Id);
        sba.PendingApprovedDeclined = 1;
        Placement pl = _db.Placements.Find(sba.PlacementId);
        if (pl.ApprovedCount == pl.PlacementSlots)
        {
            Session.Add("redirectedapprovelimit", "yes");
            return Json(View(new { @Id = sba.PlacementId }));
        }
        int i = pl.ApprovedCount;
        i++;
        pl.ApprovedCount = i;
        if (pl.PlacementSlots == pl.ApprovedCount)
        {
            pl.OpenClosedStatus = false;
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Entry(pl).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.Entry(sba).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
        //// Insert email to student stating that there application is approved
        }
        return Json(View(new { @Id = sba.PlacementId }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: I'd rather not have to use a custom command if I don't have to but it was the closed I could find to describing what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperlinks by default navigate to the URL specified in their `href` attribute. This causes a full page refresh unless prevented. What I can suggest is to use the `onclick` event instead and make an ajax request to the required action method. Here is some sample code:

### Template definition

```
template: '<a onclick="return makeRequest(this)" href="' + sitePath + 'Placement/_Approve?Id=#=Id#">Approve</button>',
```

### Ajax request implementation (put it after the grid definition)

```
<script>
function makeRequest(link) {
  // make an ajax request to the URL of the link (your action method)
  $.ajax({ 
    url: link.href 
  });
  return false; // prevent the link from navigating
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks I give this a try when I get a sec and see how it pans out.